# Find the singular solution of $ y = px + \frac{1}{p}$ using the clairaut's method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the next solution:

We know that $\frac{dy}{dx} =p$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = p + x\frac{dp}{dx} + \frac{1}{p}\frac{dp}{dx}$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = p + x\frac{dp}{dx}-\frac{1}{p^2}\frac{dp}{dx}$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx} + x\frac{dp}{dx} - \frac{1}{p^2}\frac{dp}{dx}$

$0 = \frac{dp}{dx}(x-\frac{1}{p^2})$

1) $\frac{dp}{dx} = 0$

2) $ x -\frac{1}{p^2} = 0$

Comment: Oh! yo lost interest in your problem!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have done well so far the general solution comes from $\frac{dp}{dx}=0 \implies p=m ~(contant)$
and the general solution of your ODE is $$y=mx+\frac{1}{m}.~~~(1)$$
Next, the singular (particular, fixed, essenrial and constant free) comed from your equation $$p^2=\frac{1}{x} \implies p=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\pm  \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \implies y=\mp 2\sqrt{x}\implies y^2=4x ~~~~(2).$$

The end result is a fixed parabola and the general solution (1) is a family of lines
which are tangent to this parabola.